# Copy password to clipboard using batch scripting

Tags: passwords, cmd.exe

I want to copy password to clipboard using bat file.
I have tried some suggestions like

`echo|set /p=Ps5dP%q$@mxnx|clip`

But the problem is, it does not copy % sign to clipboard. Above script works but without % sign.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: -1 KISS  Try `echo %` and `echo %|clip`  then if you have problems with percentage, then ask.  Password is irrelevant. Troubleshooting and disgnosing require that you simplify your example to demonstrate the problem. So if your problem is with % then remove the  Ps5dPq$ from your example 'cos it's just junk

Answer (score 1):

#### It does not copy % sign to clipboard

From a command line

```
F:\test>echo|set /p=Ps5dP%q$@mxnx|clip

F:\test>Ps5dP%q$@mxnx
```

The command works as expected.

---

#### From a batch file

The command does not work as expected. You can see the the `echo` in the command file has dropped the `%`.

```
F:\test>type test.cmd 
echo|set /p=Ps5dP%q$@mxnx|clip

F:\test>test

F:\test>echo | set /p=Ps5dPq$@mxnx  | clip

F:\test>Ps5dPq$@mxnx
```

---

#### Solution for a batch file

Escape the `%` (replace `%` with `%%`)

```
F:\test>type test.cmd
echo|set /p=Ps5dP%%q$@mxnx|clip

F:\test>test

F:\test>echo | set /p=Ps5dP%q$@mxnx  | clip

F:\test>Ps5dP%q$@mxnx
```

---

#### Why do I need to escape the % character?

> **Escaping Percents**
>
> The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters
>   and `FOR` parameters.
>
> To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:
>
> `%%`

Source [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo|set /p=Ps5dP%%q$@mxnx|clip
```

The `%` escapes the `%`

Comment: the % seems to show fine here  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sYWpyWqN   AND   http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pFHEE4VN

Comment: @barlop good point. I'm not sure why echoing `%` didn't work.

Comment: It works from a command line but not in a batch file.

Comment: fixed! I remembered that you need the `%%` syntax to make `%` echo

Comment: Drat, you corrected your answer while I was editing my complete answer - that's not fair ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill hehe :P I'll try not to in the future